# Redirect form to different URL based on select option element, but after I submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm new to JavaScript, and seeking for some help. I have a form with a select drop down with 5 options.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="post" onclick="javascript:location.href = this.value;">

<input id="name" name="name" size="30" type="text" value="Type your name">

<select id="option" name="Region" >
   <option value="value1.html">Option1</option>
   <option value="value2.html">Option2</option>
   <option value="value3.html">Option3</option>
   <option value="value3.html">Option4</option>
   <option value="value3.html">Option5</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

And this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        location.href=document.getElementById("option").value;
    }       
</script>
```

I tried this and doesn't work to redirect to the page I want after I submit the form! Any ideas? I need that form to work, doesn't matter if I can do it with PHP or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window.onload is executed instantly before you even get a chance to make a choice.

```
<form onsubmit="return mysubmit();">
<select id="option" name="Region" >
   <option value="value1.html">Option1</option>
   <option value="value2.html">Option2</option>
   <option value="value3.html">Option3</option>
   <option value="value3.html">Option4</option>
   <option value="value3.html">Option5</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<script>
function mysubmit(){
  //you can return false; here to prevent the form being submitted
  //useful if you want to validate the form

  window.location.href=document.getElementById('option').value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This seems to be the good way, but this redirect me to a page like this http://wwww.site.com/form.php?Region=value3.html, I need to be redirected directly to http://wwww.site.com/value3.html

Comment: Same result, redirect me to form.php?Region=value3.html

Comment: I need to be redirected to pages (value1.html , value2.html and value3.html ) not to form.php?value1.html (where the value1.html is a variable) I tried this too: location.href=document.getElementById("option").value; and doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure in the "value" of each option you're writing the full web path. I can help more if you provide an example of the exact location you'd like the page to land on.
window.location.href='http://www.test.com/'+document.getElementById('option').value;